# sql sort users by the sum of their logged distance

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I am working with a table that contains logs for users reported exercise distances. I want to rank users by the sum of their logged distance.

First I find all the User ID's:

```
select distinct wordpress_user_id from wp_exercise_log
```

Then I loop through that and get the name and sum(distance) with:

```
    foreach($users as $user) {
// DISTANCE
    $user_distance = floor($wpdb->get_var( "select sum(distance) from wp_exercise_log where wordpress_user_id='$user'"));
// FULL NAME
  $user_info = get_userdata($user);
  $full_name = $user_info-> user_firstname . ' ' . $user_info-> user_lastname;
}
```

Heres my problem: Unless I append them to a multidimensional array and sort with PHP, I'm not sure how I can rank the users.

Is there a better way to select all this data and sort it with one SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
   wordpress_user_id, 
   sum(distance) as user_distance 
from 
   wp_exercise_log 
group by 
   wordpress_user_id 
order by 
   user_distance desc
```

Please mind `ORDER BY GROUP_FUNCTION()` is always causing perfomance issues.

You may consider to add some column `user_total_distance` to your users table and update it every change in `wp_exercise_log`.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks friend!
I plan to set a limit of 5, performance shouldn't be impacted much.

Comment: @Thaevis it doesn't matter. Mysql is going to create tmp table will all of your users, then sort it by count(), and then it gonna give you the output with limit 5